# Copy screenshot to clipboard in addition to saving the file

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Within OS X 10.11.6, the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  key combination saves a screenshot to the desktop by default.

Is there a way to automatically copy the file to the clipboard (in addition to saving the file), so that the screenshot can be pasted into a document?  Maybe there is some clever why to tee and pipe the image to the clipboard?

The intent is to:

1. save screenshot to a file and
2. copy screenshot to the clipboard

with a **single** command.   Examples are always appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is an *example* of what I'd do, if I needed both, to place a **screen shot** on the **clipboard** and save it as a **file** at the same time.

I'd use **Automator** to create a **Service**<sup>1</sup>  *workflow*, to which a **keyboard shortcut** could be assigned, to run an **AppleScript** *script* to have these two events happen in conjunction with each other.

In **Automator**, *create* a new **Service**<sup>1</sup>  with the following settings:

- **Service receives (no input) in (any application)**
- *Add* a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code*
   with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown further below:
- *Save* the **Automator Service**<sup>1</sup>  as, e.g.: **Screen Shot to Clipboard and File**
- *Assign* a **shortcut**, in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**:

  - **Screen Shot to Clipboard and File**      **⇧⌘5** <sup>2</sup>

Now when you press **⇧⌘5** <sup>2</sup>  the *crosshair cursor* appears just as though you had pressed **⇧⌘4**, however after making the *selection* as normal and releasing the mouse, the *selected area* is both copied to the **clipboard** and saved to a **file** on the **Desktop**.

---

**macOS Mojave Update:**

- <sup>1</sup> <sub>In **macOS Mojave**, a *Service* in **Automator** is now called a *Quick Action*, so select that.</sub>
- <sup>2</sup> <sub>By default, **⇧⌘5** in **macOS Mojave** is by assigned to a new Screenshot feature, so try **⇧⌘6** instead.</sub>

---

The *file naming convention* is that of the **macOS** *default* for **Screen Shots** saved normally, in my region. You may need to adjust the following line of *code* for it to be as in your region:

```
set theDateTimeNow to (do shell script "date \"+%Y-%m-%d at %l.%M.%S %p\"")
```

In my region, this command produces the following example output where the *value* of the `theDateTimeNow` *variable* would be, e.g.:

```
2018-01-13 at 12.04.30 PM
```

Between the line of *code* above and the two lines that follow it in the *script*, they produce, e.g.:

```
Screen Shot 2018-01-13 at 12.04.30 PM.png
```

In **Terminal**, have a look at the *man page* for both `date` and `strftime`, in order to make adjustments to format the date and time *value* of the `theDateTimeNow` *variable*, as needed or wanted.

**Note:** Read the *comments* throughout the *example* **AppleScript** *code* so as to understand what the *script* is doing.

This was tested under **macOS** 10.13.1 and worked for me without issue.

---

## *Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    --  # Screen Shot to Clipboard and File

    --  # Clear the clipboard so the 'repeat until isReady ...' loop works properly.

    set the clipboard to ""

    --  # Copy picture of selected area to the clipboard, press: ⌃⇧⌘4
    --  # Note that on my system I need to keystroke '$' instead of '4'.
    --  # I assume this is because the 'shift' key is being pressed.        

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "$" using {control down, shift down, command down}
    end tell

    --  # Wait while user makes the selection and releases the mouse or times out.
    --  # Note that the time out also acts as an escape key press of sorts. In other
    --  # words, if the user actually presses the escape key it has no effect on this
    --  # script like it would if pressing the normal shortcut outside of the script.
    --  #       
    --  # As coded, the time out is 5 seconds. Adjust 'or i is greater than 10' and or  
    --  # 'delay 0.5' as appropriate for your needs to set a different length time out.
    --  # This means, as is, you have 5 seconds to select the area of the screen you
    --  # want to capture and let go of the mouse button, otherwise it times out.

    set i to 0
    set isReady to false
    repeat until isReady or i is greater than 10
        delay 0.5
        set i to i + 1
        set cbInfo to (clipboard info) as string
        if cbInfo contains "class PNGf" then
            set isReady to true
        end if
    end repeat
    if not isReady then
        --  # User either pressed the Esc key or timed out waiting.
        return  --  # Exit the script without further processing.
    end if

    --  # Build out the screen shot path filename so its convention is of 
    --  # the default behavior when saving a screen shot to the Desktop.

    set theDateTimeNow to (do shell script "date \"+%Y-%m-%d at %l.%M.%S %p\"")
    set theFilename to "Screen Shot " & theDateTimeNow & ".png"
    set thePathFilename to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder as string) & theFilename

    --  # Retrieve the PNG data from the clipboard and write it to a disk file.

    set pngData to the clipboard as «class PNGf»
    delay 0.5
    try
        set fileNumber to open for access thePathFilename with write permission
        write pngData to fileNumber
        close access fileNumber
    on error eStr number eNum
        try
            close access fileNumber
        end try
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon caution
    end try

    --  # Convert the POSIX path filename to an alias.

    set thePathFilename to POSIX file thePathFilename as alias

    --  # Hide the file extension as is the default.

    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set extension hidden of thePathFilename to true
        end try
    end tell

end run
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is just that, and sans the include *error handling* does not include any other as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* for any *example code* presented and or *code* written by the oneself.

Comment: This solution knocks it 'out of the park': I changed the path so that screenshots do not clutter the desktop.  I would think that the shortcut Cmd ⌘+Shift ⇧+4 could be reassigned to this procedure.   I needed to add the command 'return input' before the very last line to enable the script to save the file.

Comment: @gatorback, Yes, you could assign the Automator Service **⇧⌘4** providing you disable or change it in the Screen Shot preferences. Personally I wouldn't and chose **⇧⌘5** because it's normally not already assigned and I'd want the default to work as it's supposed to, however do what works best for you. Since the Automator Service is set to **Service receives no input**, I fail to see how adding `return input` is going to do anything. Also, as coded, the creation of the file has nothing at all to do with `input` in the AppleScript script. What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: @gatorback, You said "This solution knocks it 'out of the park'" so I would hope then that you would up vote and mark this as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: It would be nice to understand why 'return input ' was necessary: this was part of the automator's boilerplate template, which I initially commented out because it was not in the recommended script.  Although the screenshot initially was in the clipboard, it was not until 'return input' was de-commented and the file was save to the target directory.

Comment: OS X version 10.11.6

Comment: @gatorback, The purpose of `return input` in a **Run AppleScript** _action_ is to pass the `input` to the next _action_, and there is no other _action_ in the _workflow_. With the **Automator Service** set to **Service receives no input**, then the **Run AppleScript** _action_ receives no `input`, the _action_ is not even connected to the _settings_ above as if **Service receives** was set to something other then **no input** and therefore `return input` returns **nothing**, and therefore has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ posted in my answer.

Comment: @gatorback, Also, in this use case, the `on run {input, parameters}` _block_ isn't really needed and can be omitted. It works for me without the `return input` and without the `on run {input, parameters}` _block_, as it should because neither has any relevance to the actual _code_ that makes up the _scrip_ I wrote. The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer **works as is and without any issues** under OS X 10.8.5, 10.11.6 and macOS 10.13.1. I have throughly tested under the aforementioned versions of the OS and `return input` & `on run {input, parameters}` _block_ **are not necessary!**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71689/discussion-between-gatorback-and-user3439894).

Comment: Hi, just to report that with Mac OS 13.3.1 it worked perfectly out of the box I also replaced the line with the path to desktop with `set thePathFilename to POSIX path of (POSIX file "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Screenshots" as string) & theFilename`  to dump into my usual screenshots folder.