# Save screenshot to clipboard and file, simultaneously

Tags: keyboard, automator, screen-capture, copy-paste

My question is simple enough<sup>1</sup>, depending on your generosity: the steps posed in the above linked thread are straightforward, except for one small point... I can't find the **Service receives no input** step in my MacOS Mojave install. I've opened Automator, but I just don't see where that option is. Actually, I can see it in the Quick Option screen, but not in the Workflow screen.

Thus, I think this is why I'm also unable to follow the below step:

---

Assign a shortcut, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services:

Screen Shot to Clipboard and File       <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

---

That is, I don't see anywhere in the Shortcuts window to edit an existing 'Services: Screen Shot to Clipboard and File' shortcut or add a new one with the same name.

Has something changed about Automator since the otherwise awesome answer to the above linked question was first posted?

---

<sup>1</sup> I would've asked this in [Copy screenshot to clipboard in addition to saving the file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311732/copy-screenshot-to-clipboard-in-addition-to-saving-the-file) but it's locked and not only am I new to Mac, I'm also new to StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, things changed since that answer was written. In **macOS Mojave**, a _Service_ in **Automator** is now called a _Quick Action_, so select that. Also, **⇧⌘5** is by default assigned to a new Screenshot feature, so try using **⇧⌘6** instead.

Comment: I've updated the linked question for macOS Mojave.