# How to save a screenshot and copy it to clipboard in one key press?

Tags: macos, automator, screen-capture

The AppleScript code from [Copy screenshot to clipboard in addition to saving the file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311732/copy-screenshot-to-clipboard-in-addition-to-saving-the-file) doesn't work anymore. I tried Automator, but when I assign the keyboard shortcut to it, it doesn't work and gives an error (I used a new keyboard shortcut, to be safe, because <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> was also taken by screenshotting my Touch Bar).

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Automator Workflow Runner (WorkflowServiceRunner, Screenshot to Clipboard) is not allowed to send keystrokes.”

Can anybody help me with this?